# Passing the parent form on the onclick event to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to pass variables on the `onclick` event to a Javascript function. I am trying the following way, I can't get the input value in the Javascript function. (I am expecting an alert of 1.) Is it the right way of doing this? Please help.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script>
            function submit_value(form) {
                alert(form.ip.value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <form>
                <td>
                    <input id="ip" type="text" value="1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="submit_value(this)">Button</a>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script doesn't know what `form` is. You need to specify `document.forms[0].ip.value` instead.

If there are more than one form on the document then it will be better if you store the form element in variable first. You can have an id on the form for that...

`<form id="formID">`

and in submit_value function you can have

`var myForm = document.getElementById('formID');
alert(myForm.ip.value);`

**Edit:**

You can use `this.form` for onClick of anchor tag.

Comment: Better is to give your form a name and then use document.formName.ip.value

Comment: Point is there could be n number of dynamic forms like this. document.forms[0].ip.value would be like knowing which form i want to send. I want to pass the form parent to the anchor tag. How do i do it?

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but the confusion is, how to get 'formID' on the 'document.js' file? please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can do it without given the form an Id and without JQuery. See [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for details.

```js
 function test(frm) {
      const formData = new FormData(frm);
      for (var value of formData.values()) {
          console.log(value);
      }
  }
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="test(this.form)">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to this:

```
    function submit_value(form) {
        alert(document.getElementById('ip').value);
    }
```

When you write `submit_value(this)`, the value of `this` is actually the element `<a>` itself, not the form.

Comment: Point is there could be n number of dynamic forms like this. I want to pass the form parent to the anchor tag. How do i do it?

Comment: If there are many dynamic forms, then you should not use `id="ip"` since ids must be unique

Comment: @user1051505 You can use `this.form` in that case. See edit of my answer.

Comment: Generate dynamic ids can work. `id="form1_ip"`, `id="form2_ip"`

Comment: @FaisalSayed : I am searching for this.form only. Where exactly do you mean to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you can use jquery. Selectors are a lot simple with that.

Change the below form html from

```
<form>
        <td>
            <input id="ip" type="text" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:;" onClick="submit_value(this)">Button</a>
        </td>
 </form>
```

to

```
 <form>
        <td>
            <input id="ip" type="text" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="" class="mySubmitButton">Button</a>
        </td>
 </form>
```

And then your JS will look like

```
$('.mySubmitButton').click(function() {

  var inputBox = $(this).prev(); 
  alert(inputBox.val());
  return false; //This prevents the default function submit . Similar to event.preventDefault
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is everywhere. You do not need JQuery.
Why do people forget about DOM object model? 
He made everything almost in right way:

```html
    <head>
        <script>
            function submit_value() {
                alert(document.forms[0].ip.value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <form>
                <td>
                    <input name="ip" type="text" value="1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="submit_value()">Button</a>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Or you can add Form ID

```html
    <head>
        <script>
            function submit_value() {
                alert(document.forms.formid.ip.value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <form id='formid'>
                <td>
                    <input name="ip" type="text" value="1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="submit_value()">Button</a>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
```